# How to mock an @INPUT value in tests for angular component

Tags: angular, input, mocking, testcase

In my angular app, I am writing a testcase for a component which has @Input value.
How can I mock the @Input value.
The main component's testSave() method uses subComponent's InputObject's id.
When I run the testcase it says undefined is an object at 'this.subComponent.InputObject.id;'

```js
export class SubComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputObj: InputObject;
}

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() subComponent: SubComponent;

  testsave() {
  this.subComponent.InputObject.id;
  }
}

export class InputObject {
  contructor(id:string, name: string)
}
```

TestCase:

```js
 it('should save', fakeAsync(()  => {
//     const event: MockEvent = new MockEvent();
//     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainComponent);
//     component = fixture.componentInstance;
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

Since `subComponent` and `inputObj` are public you can simply override it, if you test `MainComponent` you can have something like:

```js
component.subComponent = {inputObj: {id: 'someId', name :'someName'}};
```